# Incrementally transferring PyTorch weights over a limited channel

Tags: pytorch, diff, patch

I am looking for a way to distribute a new version of PyTorch weights file to multiple computers doing inference. The connections are relatively slow, so reducing an amount of data could bring a great improvement.
So I am wondering - if there is a way to create a "diff" between the previous and new sets of weights and transmit only it instead of sending the whole file - especially considering the fact that only few layers are trainable.

Comment: If by "frozen" you mean that some parameters have `requires_grad` set to `False` then PyTorch's DDP will already avoid transmitting updates for those parameters.

Comment: More generally this sounds a lot like something that would be addressed in the field of [federated learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05629). I'm not too familiar with federated learning but there are likely some tools that address the problem of efficient communication since it's one of the primary challenges in that field.

Comment: Sorry for a misleading explanation. I am asking about distribution of an already trained model to a "fleet" of computers doing inference.